Codename One - ConnectionRequest debug
I have the following code in Codename One:
        Log.p("getPageMap,pre addToQueueAndWait");
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connectionRequest);
        Log.p("getPageMap,post addToQueueAndWait");

It executes mutiple times and retrieves data from the internet (https://api.beta.tab.com.au...).
When I run in the simulator, all is ok.
When I run on a physical phone, and monitor via logcat, two executions work ok, a third execution results in the first Log.p statement appearing, but the second Log.p statement does not appear. i.e. execution appears to "freeze" within addToQueueAndWait.
Is there further logging / debugging I can include to determine the cause of the problem?
Things I've tried: I did have a call to addNetworkErrorListener (but it did not appear to be triggered). I have overridden GZConnectionRequest's handleErrorResponseCode, handleException, postResponse and buildRequestBody with basic Log.p statements, but they don't seem to provide any useful information. Things that may impact: the website has recently changed to return gzipped json, but I think I've adjusted to this change accordingly. Cookies may be a factor - are they handled differently in the simulator vs device? Changing the priority of the CZConnectionRequest to PRIORITY_CRITICAL appears to have had a posivite impact. Should I move away from GZConnectionRequest and try an alternate approach?

That sounds like a deadlock or a race condition that you only see on the device due to the differences in performance. These things are notoriously hard to debug, especially on the device.
I would recommend migrating the code to use addToQueue if possible. It's simpler as it removes the need to deal with thread blocking. The code is a bit harder since it's asynchronous and I can't give you a direct equivalent. Something like this should generally work:
Log.p("getPageMap,pre addToQueue");
connectionRequest.addResponseListener(networkEvent -> {
    Log.p("getPageMap,post addToQueue");
});
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(connectionRequest);

Alternatively, ff you want to debug this you can do the following:

Log the current thread - this can help understand what's going on. You can even see this in the debugger.

Print the stack trace every time you reach the first line (to check for recursion). You can do that by throwing and catching an exception then using printStackTrace().

Use the APIs in NetworkManager to inspect impact. E.g. use updateThreadCount to higher/lower values (it defaults to 2) to see if this changes results. Use enumurateQueue() to list the content of the queue.



Thanks Shai, I tried a few things to debug. The most promising was enumurateQueue which told me that multiple requests were in the queue, when I thought they had completed. Just a guess that my change from ConnectionRequest to GZConnectionRequest has contributed to this problem. I will make changes to use addToQueue (and not addToQueueAndWait).

Interesting to know which connections are in the queue and why. You can try simulating a slow network connection on the simulator using the menu or by tethering to the device and see if you can reproduce the problem then.

Thanks Shai. All of the connections are of a similar type e.g. https://webapi.tab.com.au/v1/tab-info-service/racing/dates/2024-04-04/meetings?jurisdiction=QLD (these change daily to include the current date). After my last comment, I changed my approach again, after watching your video (https://www.codenameone.com/how_di_i/how-do-i-use-http-sockets-webservices-websockets.html), I've switched from ConnectionRequest to URL (codenameone io) and GZIPInputStream and things appear to be more stable.

I can't see the content of the link: "It appears you are visiting our website from a country we are unable to give access to.".

Shai, thanks, it's a gambling website that may not be accessible outside of Australia. (VPN?) Here is a copy of the JSON, although that may not help. I'm unsure the content is the problem, it may be the website and access itself. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1485Yfy2IM1AMN0e1_1MX74S5i8WMPe30/view?usp=sharing

The JSON code is probably not enough to understand/debug this issue. But I understand it's resolved for now, right?
